# How to skip the first row in CSV that is not the "header row" with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, ruby-on-rails-5

The CSV:

```
Arbitrary data to skip
Name, ID, Hobby, ...
Joe, 1, Movies....
```

How to skip the first line, but still use the 2nd line with `headers: true`?

Comment: It's true that it is a duplicate but all the answers are no good.

Comment: you can do this:
 text = File.readlines("file.csv")[1..-1].join()
 then 
 csv = CSV.parse(text, headers: true)

Comment: The answers in the exemplar look good to me.